# How to explicitly use lib.d.ts types?

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, typescript2.0

> Seems like this issue is related with IDE WebStorm. I reported to WebStorm. And track [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23021).

I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript 2.

How to explicitly use the location from **lib.d.ts** types? Because now it shows red in my IDE WebStorm 2016.3 EAP:

```
const hostname = location.hostname;
const hostname = window.location.hostname;
```

[image]

---

I have this in my file:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private _location: Location) {}
// note there is an underline before
// and when I use in other functions, I actually use 'this._location' not just '_location'
```

And I found that after removing `import { Location } from '@angular/common';`, the error will be gone though.

---

And I guess the reason this error shows is because that the IDE thinks this is a `location` from Angular 2.

You can see from the screenshot below that all functions which belongs to `Location` from Angular 2.

[image]

---

One way is using `const hostname = (location as any).hostname;`, but is there any better way? Thanks

My **tsconfig.json** if it helps:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "!node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]` line from the `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @NitzanTomer still same

Comment: There must be a confusion between the [angular Location](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/common/src/location/location.ts#L47) and the [builtin Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), as for why I'm not sure. Is it just an intellisense error or does the compilation fail? Have you tried to run it? Does it fail at runtime as well?

Comment: @NitzanTomer just intellisense error, now I feel it is more like an issue of Webstorm. I will report to Webstorm.

Comment: Try to import the angular location under a different name, let say `AngularLocation`, maybe that will let you get rid of the error?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I use `import { Location as Location2 } from '@angular/common';` and `constructor(private _location: Location2) {}`, it does solve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @NitzanTomer's help.

It seems like this issue is related with WebStorm.

I reported it to WebStorm, you can track the issue here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23021